# Nothing is coming up when I create a boxplot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I am trying to make a multiple box plot using matplotlib of 'Gender' and 'Score'. I entered this code just to see a singular box plot first for Males but the box is just completely blank.

Input:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Males = [df.loc[df['Gender']=='Male', 'Score']]
Females = [df.loc[df['Gender']=='Female', 'Score']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(Males)
plt.show()
```

When I check whether there is in fact data:

```
Males = [print(df.loc[df['Gender']=='Male', 'Score'])]
Females = [print(df.loc[df['Gender']=='Female', 'Score'])]
```

There is:

```
0        NaN
1      22.11
4      28.66
5      32.41
6      62.57

etc.
```

So what's going on?

Comment: Can you maybe show us what your dataframe looks like?

Comment: i figured it out actually thanks!!

Comment: Consider removing the "print" from your statement :-)

Comment: oh yes that was a typo haha thanks!